# Open link through facebook app

Tags: java, android

I have a facebook page and want to open it through the Facebook App and not through the browser. How to do so ?

For example the amazon page which is: https://www.facebook.com/Amazon

I tried this:

```
            String uri = "facebook://facebook.com/amazon";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the Facebook App but now the facebook page.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/"+FB_ID));
//or  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/"+FB_ID));
startActivity(intent);
```

where FB_ID - ID of group

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it. Had to use this:

"fb://page/9465008123"